# Book about a boy with dangerous fire powers

Tags: story-identification, novel, powers

It's been about five years, so I'm not really sure, but I think it's a novel and one of the main characters is a boy who thought he didn't have powers because his mother was a normal human who married a powerful man, his father. He was friends with this girl who had a disability(?), but was also powerful. I don't remember much, but something that stuck out was how weird their names were, like they couldn't actually be pronounced.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be Ursula le Guin's [*Gifts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gifts_(novel))?

> The narrator Orrec is from the domain of Caspromant, where the hereditary gift is the power of "unmaking", which can kill or destroy at a glance; his friend Gry is from the neighboring domain of Roddmant, and her lineage has the ability to call animals.

> His father Canoc is the brantor of Caspromant; his mother Melle, a woman from the lowlands.

> The Caspros visit Drummant, but Ogge is rude to them, and the granddaughter Ogge proposed to betroth to Orrec is found to be mentally disabled.

The main character is a boy who is supposed to have dangerous powers inherited from his father. He's friends with a girl, Gry, who has a different kind of supernatural power, but it's another girl who has a disability. The names seem like pretty standard fantasy fare to me, but they might be difficult to pronounce if you're not used to such.